# How to show that group of order 15 is cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $15$ then prove that it is cyclic.

By Lagrange's theorem, its non identity elements can only have order $3$ or $5$. Not all non identity elements are of order $\displaystyle 5$ because $\displaystyle \phi ( 5) =4$ does not divide $14$.

If all non identity elements are of order $\displaystyle 3$ then $G$ is of the form:

$\displaystyle G=\left\{1,a_{1} ,a_{1}^{2} ,a_{2} ,a_{2}^{2} ,\cdots ,a_{7} ,a_{7}^{2}\right\}$

$\displaystyle a_{1} a_{2} \in \left\{a_{i}^{r} :\ 3\leq i\leq 7,\ 1\leq r\leq 2\right\}$

Case 1: WLOG $\displaystyle a_{1} a_{2} =a_{3}$

By $\displaystyle a_{3}^{2} =a_{3}^{-1}$, we have $\displaystyle a_{1} a_{2} a_{1} a_{2} =a_{2}^{2} a_{1}^{2}$

How do I get a contradiction here?

Case 2: WLOG $\displaystyle a_{1} a_{2} =a_{3}^{2}$

How do I get a contradiction here?

If I establish that there must exist at least one order 5 element (say b) then,

Clearly, $\displaystyle |\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle|=1$

Cosets of $\displaystyle \langle a \rangle $ are $\displaystyle \langle a \rangle, b\langle a \rangle, b^{2} \langle a \rangle,\ b^{3} \langle a \rangle, b^{4} \langle a \rangle $

Suppose $\displaystyle G$ is not cyclic, then for any $\displaystyle g\in G,\ |g|\neq 15$.

$\displaystyle  |G/Z( G) |=\frac{15}{|Z( G) |} \in \{15,5,3,1\}$

From here, I plan to show that $\displaystyle |Z( G) |=15$ so that $\displaystyle G=Z( G) \Longrightarrow G$ is abelian.

So I must reject the following:

$\displaystyle Z( G) \in \{1,3,5\}$

I have no idea how to do this either and even if I somehow manage to do this, I have no idea how to proceed further to show $G$ is cyclic.

I'll appreciate any hint in this. I would also like to mention that following are not allowed:

<s>1. Cauchy's theorem</s>

2. Sylow's theorems
3. Group actions

Lagrange's theorem, Cosets, External direct products, Internal direct products, factor groups (quotient groups) etc. are allowed.

Comment: Why are those three results listed near the end "not allowed"?  Please explain why you are trying to learn math under such constraints.  For example, is this a homework question with rules imposed by the instructor?

Comment: @KCd: This is an exercise problem in Herstein's topics in algebra. By that chapter, Sylow's theorems, Group actions have not yet been introduced.  That's why I ask.

Comment: Aha, I was wondering if it was an exercise from Herstein. I found the exercise in my copy (2nd edition) and it is an exercise for the section where Cauchy's theorem is proved, so I'd consider trying to avoid the use of Cauchy's theorem as unreasonable.

Comment: @KCd: I probably skipped that exercise :-) But that will establish that there must exist element of order 5 also. Even if that is done, the problem still remains.

Comment: @VishnuKadiri: No I didn't but I think it easily follows from $|G/Z(G)|=|G|/|Z(G)|=r>1$,say. Then $|G|/r=|Z(G)|$. If $|G|=ps$ , where p is odd prime then $r|s$ and hence $p|Z(G)$.

Comment: @Koro, sorry, I was meaning to say that if prime p | |G|, then there is an element g, such that |g|=p. This is Cauchy's theorem. Did you know this?

Comment: @VishnuKadiri: As pointed out in comments above, yes, I am allowed to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $G/Z(G)$ cannot have a prime order. If it did, then $G/Z(G)$ would be a cyclic group, making $G$ abelian, making $G=Z(G)$ so that $|G/Z(G)|=1$ which is a contradiction. So, the only possible order of $Z(G)$ are $1$ and $15$. If $|Z(G)|=15$, then we are done as $Z(G)=G$. Now, suppose $|Z(G)|=1$. Then, use the class equation. We note that $|\mathcal{K}(x)|=1$ iff $x \in Z(G)$. Since $|Z(G)|=1$, every non-identity element $g$, is such that $|\mathcal{K}(g)| \in \{3,5\}$. So, $|G|=|Z(G)|+\displaystyle\sum|\mathcal{K}(g)|$. Since $|\mathcal{K}(g)| \in \{3,5\}$, $\displaystyle\sum\mathcal{K}(g)$ is a linear combination of $3$ and $5$ i.e $\displaystyle\sum\mathcal{K}(g)=3a+5b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. So, $15=1+3a+5b$, which is clearly a contradiction. Hence, $|Z(G)| \neq 1 \implies |Z(G)|=15$.

**EDIT**: Answer without using class equation. Every element in $G$ will have order $1,3,5,15$ from Lagrange's theorem. If there is some element of order $15$ then we are done. Suppose not. From Cauchy's theorem, there is an element of order 3, and there is an element of order $5$. Let $|p|=3$ and $|q|=5$. Let $P=<p>$ and $Q=<q>$. It is clear that $P \cap Q \leq P$ and $P \cap Q \leq Q$ hence, $|P \cap Q| \mid |P|,|Q| \implies |P \cap Q|=1$. Consider $PQ$. It has order $|PQ|=\frac{|P||Q|}{|P \cap Q|}=3\cdot 5=|G|$. Hence, $G=PQ$. We know that $AB$ is a subgroup of $G$, iff $AB=BA$ where $A,B$ are subgroups of $G$. Hence, $PQ=QP$, $PQP^{-1}=Q$. It is obvious that if $a \in Q$, then $a^{-1}Qa=Q$. The other elements of $G$ not in $Q$ will be in $P$ and from above $PQP^{-1}=Q$. Thus, $g^{-1}Qg=Q, \forall g \in G$, so that $Q \triangleleft G$ and similarly, $P \triangleleft G$. Now, we have $P,Q$ are abelian because they are cyclic and $P \cap Q=\{e\}$. Let $a \in P$ and $b \in Q$. Then $a(ba^{-1}b^{-1})=(aba^{-1})b^{-1} \in P,Q \implies aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in P \cap Q=\{e\}$, so $ab=ba$. Thus, for any $g(=p_1q_1), h(=p_2q_2) \in G$, $gh=p_1q_1p_2q_2=p_2q_2p_1q_1=hg$, so $G$ is abelian, hence $|pq|=15 \implies G=<pq>$.

Comment: I am afraid class equation is not allowed as it's part of Sylow's I think.

Comment: You don't need Sylow's to understand the class equation.

Comment: Hi Vishnu! (This is unrelated) I remember you a s a jee aspirant,and I was under a different username (Quantum) How did your jee adv go?

Comment: Hey @AlbusDumbledore! My JEE Adv was not that great (as expected). I got a rank of 2399, thanks to Chemistry >:( But am now in CMI for Math :) so would say it worked out well! I would like to know more about you!

Comment: sorry for the late response (I was being bombarded with mock test after mocktest) I am in 12th and have perhaps 2-3 more months before advanced.would like to know what to do  and what not to do.It shall be great if we could continue in chat rather than incur the wrath of mods while discussing something unrelated here.By the way congrats on getting 2399 in an exam written by 2-lakh students all over india

Comment: @Koro, the class equation (page 85 of Herstein's) is not really part of Sylow's theory (page 91 and thereafter of Herstein's).